# Required regex to match word example - "active users"

Tags: regex, match

Guys could you please help on creating a Regex for below Scenario.

I'm trying to create regex to match file name *active users* in wildcard.

Tried the basic one but doesn't work `(?i)^active users$`

example:

1. Regex should match the word(active users) with case insensitive

- AcTiVE Users
- active users
- ACTIVE USERS

2. Regex should also match the word(active users) even though character present in prefix and suffix

- Active users_test
- Test_ACTIVE USERS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude matching word characters without the underscore at the left and at the right instead of using the anchors.

```
(?i)(?<![^\W_])active users(?![^\W_])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQk4aZ/1)

Comment: This perfectly works for all the below
Active users_test,
Test_ACTIVE USERS,
AcTiVE Users, active users, ACTIVE USERS

But not for 
TestActive users,
or Active usersTest

Comment: @sathish But in that case you can use `(?i)active users` without any boundaries https://regex101.com/r/ySnNol/1

Comment: @sathish Is it related?

Comment: Hi I have one more requirement if possible will you able to help?

1. Regex should match any prefix like "xxxxxxxxxx" & file type .pdf and keyword "sat" but no suffix after "sat" or "pdf" example : Prefix(XXX)sat.pdf
2. Regex should only match pdf file extension (.pdf) and any prefix and suffix along with "Active members" keyword but not after the file type
example: prefix(XXXX)Active members(XXXX)suffix.pdf

Comment: You might use an approach like `.*active members.*\.pdf` or without spaces `\S*active members\S*\.pdf` https://regex101.com/r/EybDLZ/1

Comment: This case will also match "asdasdActive members.pdfasdasdasd" which have suffix :-). we need to match only any prefix character & Active members".pdf" end with it.

Comment: Can you add some example what you do and do not want to match on https://regex101.com/ and then save it and share it here?